# Insert Meta Box info into shortcode

Tags: shortcode, meta-boxes

I am trying to pull a meta box field into a shortcode, but cannot seem to get the following to output anything to the screen. Any suggestions? Basically I have a meta box for a Gallery ID, which the client only puts in a number. I need that number to be put next to gallery_ids=

```
<?php
$galleryid = ''; 
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
$galleryid = get_post_meta($post ->ID, '_cd_gallery_ID', true);
endwhile; 
echo do_shortcode('[ngg_images gallery_ids=$galleryid display_type=photocrati nextgen_pro_horizontal_filmstrip)');
else: 
endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making it harder then it needed to be - the following code worked perfect..

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[ngg_images gallery_ids="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cd_gallery_ID', true).'" display_type="photocrati-nextgen_pro_horizontal_filmstrip"]'); ?>
```